# Outlook reply to multiple emails on demand

Tags: vba, outlook

Just wondering if this is possible and if it is can someone assist me with?

In this scenario what we do is emails comes into shared folder.  We will then have those email sorted.

After the sorting we will start putting emails into an approved folder.  What I will like to do is have a VBA macro in outlook that will be able to generate a custom reply to all the emails in the approved folder.

For example if we place 5 emails in the folder and run a script it should send emails out to those 5 senders.

The email will be something generic such as "You are approved, please logout a "time".

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest starting from the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN. It explains the basics of programming VBA macros.

The [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event is fired when one or more items are added to the Items collection (i.e. folder). Be aware, the event is not fired when a large number of items are added to the folder at once.

So, you can handle the ItemAdd event of the approved folder to create and send a reply. The [Reply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868875(v=office.15).aspx) method of Outlook items creates a reply, pre-addressed to the original sender, from the original message. The [Send](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff866779(v=office.15).aspx) method sends the e-mail message. For example:

```
 Public WithEvents myOlItems As Outlook.Items 

 Public Sub Initialize_handler()  
   Set myOlItems = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items  
 End Sub 

 Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)  
  Dim myOlMItem As Outlook.MailItem  
  Dim myOlAtts As Outlook.Attachments  

  Set myOlMItem = myOlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
  myOlMItem.Save  
  Set myOlAtts = myOlMItem.Attachments  
  ' Add new contact to attachments in mail message  
  myOlAtts.Add Item, olByValue  
  myOlMItem.To = "Sales Team"  
  myOlMItem.Subject = "New contact"  
  myOlMItem.Send  
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> Outlook reply to multiple emails on demand

Paste the following code in **`"ThisOutlookSession"`**

Outlook will automatically send a reply when you move Emails to **"approved"** folder

```
Option Explicit
 '// items in the target folder to events
Dim WithEvents TargetFolderItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set olNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set TargetFolderItems = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) _
                                         '// Set your folder here
                                         .Folders.Item("approved").Items

End Sub

'// ItemAdd event code
Sub TargetFolderItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Dim olReply As MailItem

    Set olReply = Item.Reply
        olReply.HTMLBody = "You are approved " & vbCrLf & olReply.HTMLBody
        olReply.Send

    Set TargetFolderItems = Nothing
    Set olReply = Nothing

End Sub
```